# Android Tablet as input to Windows PC

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, android, tablet, touchscreen

I have a new computer, but as it is company provided, I had very little agency over feature choice. One thing I really want is to be able to use the draw features on MS Office. But, unfortunately, my computer does not have a touch screen.

My work is not related to graphics designing, so buying a Wacom tablet does not make sense. I was wondering whether it is possible to use Android tablets to mirror displays and use them as an input device too.

I know there are apps like [IDisplay](http://www.getidisplay.com/) that allow mirroring, but I could not find anywhere whether they make the tablets work as input devices too.

I am also open to other solutions. I do not currently own a tablet, so I will need to buy one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use various apps to use a tablet or phone as a keyboard or mouse.

However, I wouldnt recommend it.  The apps arent designed for continuous use and I feel you would find it more cumbersome than useful.  There is also some input lag, connectivity issues, and no fine control, so actual drawing might be hard to do.  I can say from personal experience this isnt a good option.

In all honesty, getting a drawing tablet would be the best choice.  Wacom and other brands do make [cheap drawing tablets](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=drawing%20tablet&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Adrawing%20tablet) under $25.  You do not have to spend a lot of money to get what you want.